TypeError: this.sequelize.runHooks is not a function
// user.js
'use strict';

const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model { }

  User.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      comment: '用户ID',
    },
  
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW // 默认值为当前时间
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW // 默认值为当前时间
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
    timestamps: true, // 启用时间戳
    createdAt: 'createdAt', // 自定义或确认创建时间字段名
    updatedAt: 'updatedAt', // 自定义或确认更新时间字段名
  });

  return User;
};

//model/index.js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../../database/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;

I tried to modify the use
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }

The above is the model folder generated by sequelize-cli, which contains two files: one is the index.js file generated by default, and the other is the model file. The migration file has been configured. But when I run the project npm run dev, it says equelize.runHooks is not a function. The same thing happens when I modify the reference document: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/

Please show the full error text and stacktrace in the poist
